# Contact Form with pop up Modal Success or Fail Box

Tags: javascript, php

Hi everyone and first thanks in advance for any help that is given. I have searched the database here and not really found the solution to my problem. I'm having difficulty in getting my PHP script to align with my HTML and javascript. I'm trying to create a pop up modal box on contact form submission. With my current code i am just getting the fail box pop up. Can anyone see where my coding error is? Many Thanks again.

HTML -

```
<div class="col-md-7 contact-form">
                    <form action="contact.php" method="post" form id="contact-form">
                        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required>
                        <input type="email" class="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <textarea placeholder="Message" name="Message" required></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>   
            </div>
<div class="modal fade" id="thankyouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
          <h2 class="modal-title text-center" style="font-weight: 600; color: #393939;">THANKS</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center" style="background-color: #fff;">
          <p style="font-weight: 600; color: #393939; font-size: 18px;">We will contact you as soon as possible!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #fff; border-top: 0px solid #fff;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

  <div id="fail-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Ace Motorcycles</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Sorry something went wrong in sending your message. Please try again</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#contact-form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        request = $.ajax({
          url: "process.php",
          type: "post",
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          dataType:"json"
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (response, textStatus){
          if (response == true ) {
            console.log('true');
            $('#thankyouModal').modal('show');
          } else {
            console.log('false');
            $('#fail-modal').modal('show');
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (textStatus, errorThrown){
          // Log the error to the console
          console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+ textStatus, errorThrown
          );
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

contact.php -

```
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Website Enquiry';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'timmy2872@gmail.com';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('Name' => 'Name', 'Email' => 'Email', 'Message' => 'Message'); 

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, we will get back to you very soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

/*
 *  LET'S DO THE SENDING
 */

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage); 
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage); 
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

process.php -

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$sent = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {     
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "timmy2872@gmail.com";

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $sender = $_POST['Email'];

    $name = $_POST['Name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['Email']; // required
    $message = $_POST['Message']; //required

    $email_message = "Below is the message.\n\n";

    $email_subject = "Contact details - $name";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email Address: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From:'.$sender."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $sent= @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
}

die(json_encode($sent));

?>
```

Comment: Did you check for any errors using the F12 tools of the browser you use?

Comment: Hi @JeroenHeier yes i did and nothing obvious seems to be showing up unless i am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was here -

```
     $("#contact-form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Should of been -

```
     $("#contact").on("submit", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
```